# How to close Joptionpane showOptionDialog by using button action event in option box

Tags: java

I had created my own buttons in joption pane because I need to color button and disable one of it's for my functionality.when i click on other enabled button the Joption pane is not getting closed,Here i need to click on cross button of the dialog to close this.

Can any one tell me how to close Joption pane upon button action event.

```
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton jb = new JButton(" Yes ");
    jb.setBackground(Color.RED);
    jb.setEnabled(false);
            JButton jb1 = new JButton(" No ");

           jb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
             {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                   {

            System.out.println("No action");
        }
    });

    Object[] options = { jb, jb1 };
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea(" *Note : some message !");
    area.setForeground(Color.red);
    int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame, area, " Alert ", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null,options,options[0]);
```

On clicking, no button Joption pane dialog needs to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the listener you can do this:

```
jb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Window w = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(jb1);
        w.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great !! @Simone thanks for the help it worked as expected.